# Can't determine if PHPMailer is working

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a php page containing PHPMailer. Apperently it was working in both the test server and the production server. It was in a separate php file, but since I need to do send different kinds of email with different alert messages on screen, I placed my code on the same php file as my form.

What I did is:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{

require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    if(isset($_POST['feedback_mail']))
    {

            $mail->Host       = "my mail host"; // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;  

            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = "the account that I will be using"; // SMTP account username
            $mail->Password   = "my password";          

            $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['Email'], $_POST['Name']);
            $mail->AddAddress('address to where I will send it', 'Name');
            $mail->SetFrom($_POST['Email'], $_POST['Name']);

            $mail->Subject = 'Subject'.$_POST['Subject'];
            $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
            $mail->MsgHTML($_POST['Body']);     

            $mail->Send();  
            $marker = 1;

            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                $marker = 0;
            } else {
                $marker = 1;
                    }
        }
}
```

When I try to send an email message, it says that the message is sent, but I have been waiting for almost an hour but there is still no message recieved on my email. I know that my test server allows sending of email because I also have another application that can send mails. And I am using the same account for sending these mails. How do I know if PHPMailer is really working or not?

**EDIT:** I found out it might probably be my local network connection that's stopping the mail. I just tried running the from on a VPN connection and somehow it recieved an email.

Either my  network connection is having problems or the server is deliberately blocking IP's  from my country.

Comment: Why are you setting the `from` value as the posted `email` value? that doesn't make sense, unless you're trying to spoof. Further, if your mail server is configured correctly, it will not work.

Comment: PHPMailer can only say that it's successfully handed the email off to your outgoing mail server. After that, it's **utterly** out of PHPmailer's hands. You need to check your mail server logs to see what happened to the mail from that point onwards. Most likely it's gotten ditched as spam by the receiving end. And note that as written, you'd be allowing ANYONE to send EMAIL anywhere... in other words, this script is begging to get abused as a spam source.

Comment: It actually worked jsut now, but I had to use VPN connection on a US IP. It's really weird, or could it be my local network that's preventing me?

Comment: I guess the problem is no longer with the code itself

Comment: What are your smtp server settings?  Are you sending through gmail?  If so, try experimenting with the ports and other settings.